# Ubicar objetos en la mitad de un form

Tags: html, css

Tengo el siguiente codigo

```css
body {}

.PrincipalForm {
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid #666666;
  width: 310px;
  height: 600px;
}

.TblLogin {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#usuario {
  width: 150px;
}

#password {
  width: 150px;
}

#Aceptar {
  width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Login</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estiloLogin.css" />
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>

<body>
  <form class="PrincipalForm">
    <table class="TblLogin">
      <tr>
        <label>Usuario:</label>
      </tr><br>
      <tr>
        <input type="text" id="usuario">
      </tr><br>
      <tr>
        <label>Password:</label>
      </tr><br>
      <tr>
        <input type="password" id="password">
      </tr><br>
      <tr>
        <button type="button" id="Aceptar">Aceptar</button>
      </tr><br>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Solo que necesito centrarlo para que se muestre de esta menera:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Antes que todo, mucho ojo con la estructura de la tabla, no cerraste la etiqueta y olvidaste utilizar las etiquetas TD. Si no los utilizas, algunos navegadores pueden anular la tabla y removiendo sus propiedades en el proceso.

El escribir mal la estructura de la tabla provocó que tu formulario no se alineara horizontalmente.

Ahora, para alinear un elemento en vertical existen varios trucos con CSS, uno de ellos es tratar de que dos elementos se comporten como si fueran una tabla con una celda en su interior de forma que el que se comporte como celda posea las propiedades de una celda HTML y pueda ser alineada verticalmente.

En este caso modifique tu código para que el formulario posea la propiedad `display: table` y cree un div que contenga a tu tabla, cual tendrá la propiedad `display: table-cell`.

```css
body {}

.PrincipalForm {
margin: 0 auto;
border: 1px solid #666666;
width: 310px;
height: 600px;
}

table td{
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom:10px;
}

.centrar{
  display: table;
}
.centrar>div{
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.TblLogin {
margin: 0 auto;
}

#usuario {
width: 150px;
}

#password {
width: 150px;
}

#Aceptar {
width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Login</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estiloLogin.css" />
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>

<body>
  <form class="PrincipalForm centrar">
    <div>
      <table class="TblLogin">
        <tr>
          <td><label>Usuario:</label></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input type="text" id="usuario"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><label>Password:</label></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input type="password" id="password"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><button type="button" id="Aceptar">Aceptar</button></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
  </form>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Para alinear tu formulario horizontalmente usa

```
text-align: center;
```

y para alinearlo verticalmente:

```
display:table-cell;
vertical-align:middle;
```

```css
body {}

.PrincipalForm {
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid #666666;
  width: 310px;
  height: 600px;
  text-align: center;
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;
}

.TblLogin {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#usuario {
  width: 150px;
}

#password {
  width: 150px;
}

#Aceptar {
  width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Login</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estiloLogin.css" />
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>

<body>
  <form class="PrincipalForm">
    <table class="TblLogin">
      <tr>
        <label>Usuario:</label>
      </tr><br>
      <tr>
        <input type="text" id="usuario">
      </tr><br>
      <tr>
        <label>Password:</label>
      </tr><br>
      <tr>
        <input type="password" id="password">
      </tr><br>
      <tr>
        <button type="button" id="Aceptar">Aceptar</button>
      </tr><br>
      </table>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Solo necesitas agregar `text-align: center` a tu forma asi:

```css
body {}

.PrincipalForm {
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid #666666;
  width: 310px;
  height: 600px;
  text-align: center;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.TblLogin {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#usuario {
  width: 150px;
}

#password {
  width: 150px;
}

#Aceptar {
  width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Login</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estiloLogin.css" />
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>

<body>
  <form class="PrincipalForm">
    <table class="TblLogin">
      <tr>
        <label>Usuario:</label>
      </tr><br>
      <tr>
        <input type="text" id="usuario">
      </tr><br>
      <tr>
        <label>Password:</label>
      </tr><br>
      <tr>
        <input type="password" id="password">
      </tr><br>
      <tr>
        <button type="button" id="Aceptar">Aceptar</button>
      </tr><br>
      </table>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: ya edite mi respuesta